# Fetch MULTIPLE "Person or Group" values based on lookup selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, caml-query, spservices

I have a list "List1" having following fields

Department : Single line of text

HOD : Person or group(Multiple values)

There is another list called "List2" with following fields

FacultyName : Single line of text

Dept : Lookup ("Department" column of "List1")

HOD : Person or Group(Multiple values)

My query is how to auto-populate HOD field in "List2" based on the "Dept" lookup selection.

It should fetch values from corresponding HOD field of "List1".

Here the HOD fields have multiple values. I have the solution for fetching single "Person or group" value, but I need the solution for fetching **Multiple** values.

I am using SharePoint online.

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you will have already discovered the option to display a multi-person field does not appear when you are specifying a lookup field in List2. The only way I can see you achieving this is via a workflow using Sharepoint Designer. This would be triggered when you create or modify a record in List2.

**Steps**

- Create List1 as you have done already
- In List 2 create a field called HOD. Specify this as a Person or Group and allow multiple values. We are going to populate this in the workflow.
- The next steps assume you have Sharepoint Designer Installed;
- Create a List Workflow on List2
- Add a "Set Field in Current Item" action; Set *field* to *value*
- Set the *field* to HOD
- Set the *value* to a lookup from List1
  [image]
- In the Find the List Item section the Field is Department (from List1) and the Value is Department from CurrentItem (i.e. List2). You specify this by clicking on the *fx* button.
- You must specify the Return field as Lookup Value (as Text) or the lookup will fail
  [image]
- Finally, remember to select on Create and Modify under the workflow start conditions
  [image]

Here is the item in List1;
[image]

And here is the item in List2 for a lookup to Department A after the workflow has run;
[image]

Hope this helps?!

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my requirement. I want it to be done using code, not by workflow. Could you help me with that?

Comment: If you post an example of the code you are using to solve the problem for a single person/group then I might be able to help. It is not clear from your post when you are triggering the event to fetch the multiple person/group from List1; is it when you have selected the Department? Is this in Add New Item view? Context always helps.